# How do US states maintain a secret ballot using Voter Verified Paper Audit Trail?

Tags: united-states, election, voting, election-security, secret-ballot

How have US states implemented [Voter Verified Paper Audit Trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voter-verified_paper_audit_trail) in their voting systems? In particular, **how is the secrecy of votes insured?**

I note that it would be compromised if bulletins where sequentially printed on a continuous roll of paper, or it bulletins where cut but somewhat stacked in order, or the machine opened during the voting process with one record (or few) in the VVPAT. Independently, there's the risk of compromise by the printing process (thru noise if mechanical, or electromagnetic emission).

Context: I'm French, and have never seen VVPAT operating (our few voting machines have been designed in the previous century, and use an electronic record of individual votes, which makes it impossible for a voter to verify it). Link to a video showing a common US system operating would be great.

Comment: Why do you think secrecy is a problem? The paper audit trail doesn't have anything identifying the voter on it.

Comment: Why does it matter if they're stacked in order? There's no record anywhere of the order that people voted, so the order of the stack doesn't tell you who each ballot was from.